# integrating the zxing barcode code in my application

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

Hey i want to integrate the zxing code in my application.
I dont want to call the barcode application i want the barcode functionality code in my application. I have downloaded the package files then if i integrate it in my application i rename the package also and den i have error in

import package.R; line

Thanks

Comment: "I have an error" that's really easy to help you! Maybe you can tell us at least the error message. By the way, I think that you took the code without having at least read the licenses..

Answer (score 0):

when you copy/paste, eclipse automatically tries adding the resource files of the package from which you are stealing code. delete that import line.

Comment: but still there are like huge number of errors it is unable to import some classes since eclipse can not find those classes in the build and i even wonder why are not those classes there since i just copied the complete package into my src

Comment: did you copy the .java or the jar?

Comment: all the class files under android folder